# "Serial Upvoting Reversed" points seem to be incorrectly credited

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

The overall point is a complicated situation involving a downvote on a removed post, serial upvotes and their reversal.  Normally, a downvote can be "made up" with additional upvotes beyond 20.  However, this issue has arisen because the points were made up a serial upvoter (and then reversed) so there is no opportunity to "make them up".  (I'm not sure if removing the downvoted post was important, but it made it harder to spot the problem.)

Here is more detail:

On Sep 6th (yesterday as I write this), I had a bunch of serial upvotes.  Most of these occurred *after* I had hit the 200 point up-vote threshold for the day (so they did not affect points gathered).  But, one was apparently worth +2 points, making up the points on a downvote from a removed post.  Although the daily point total for yesterday reflects the +2 points, I don't think my total points reflected the +2.

On Sep 7th (today), the first thing that happened was a "Serial Upvoting Reversal" for the +2 points (so -2 points).  Fine.  That makes sense.  The -2 points have been deducted from the total score.  However, it doesn't seem that the +2 were ever really added in.

The net effect is that it looks like I've had a down vote (or 2 points deduction) when that hasn't occurred.  Also, I can't make up these points by getting extra up votes beyond 20.  Both today and yesterday there have been such "excess" points to make this up.

In any case, it seems that the reversal process is not perfect in this situation.  Perhaps there is another step and tomorrow morning the reversal will be fixed.

Comment: An upvote can be worth 2 points if you're up to 198 for the day, though I can't yet make sense of that total... A downvote, upvote and rapid undownvote perhaps?

Comment: Did you downvote anyone?  Two downvotes on answers would be 2 points.  Just spitballing here, but did you try the [rep recalculation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)?

Comment: @bluefeet . . . There were no actions other than upvotes and accepts.  I noticed this because my point score was a multiple of 5 before this occurred.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, are you showing removed posts in your reputation?  I wonder if you had an edit that you got 2 rep points from removed which would cause a loss of 2 points, then you got an upvote of 2 because you were near the rep cap. That might explain the strange +2 upvote.

Comment: @bluefeet . . . A removed post with a downvote explains the +2 yesterday.  I revised the question.  Now the mystery is why those points were not made up by extra upvotes yesterday or today.  The downvote would have been made up.  The reversal on the serial upvote apparently cannot be.

Comment: It looks correct to me currently - there is a removed post that cost you 10 rep, and with conjunction with a downvote and two +2s for upvotes, altogether a -8 (-12 + 4) which is exactly what I see on the page (305 - 8 = 297).

Comment: What happens when you go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and trigger a recalculation?